# Cannot load the csv file in Weka

Tags: database, csv, weka

I have tried many times to load this *.csv file, but I failed. I am using Weka 3.7
Here is the error:
**Wrong number of mumber. Read 1,expected 12, read Token[EOL], line 2**
This is the line 2 in my file:
7;0.27;0.36;20.7;0.045;45;170;1.001;3;0.45;8.8;6
I dont know what wrong with this?
Someone helps me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried **csv** files instead of "semicolon separated values"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried to import a semi-colon delimited file as a CSV for opening into Weka, but what appeared to happen was that the contents were loaded up as a single attribute (due to the lack of commas in the file structure).  I didn't get the error that you had reported.

What you would need to do is replace all of the semi-colons to be commas and then load the contents again.  In your above case, I assumed that the first line contained the attribute names, which loaded successfully in my test case.

As such, the format Weka is likely expecting is the [Comma-Separated Values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) Format.